# Multiline mat-tooltip on mat-table cell is not working

Tags: css, angular, tooltip, mat-table

I made mat-tooltip as multiline with following style in global css.

```
 .mat-tooltip-class-here {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
 }
```

This is working on span and button but not on mat cell.

**see on span** (Working):

[image: tooltip on span]

**see on button** (Working):

[image]

**see on table cell** (Not working):

[image]

Not sure what is issue. I have created stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mtwsw

Answer (score 0):

There is inconsistency in terms of new line chars.

For the button and span `&#13;` works as new line but for the table cell, we might need to use `\r\n` or `\n`.

IDK the exact reason for this but its working right now. One thing to be notice, any popover style need to be applied at global css level as it render directly inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with mat table while using mat-tooltip but a workaround is there for this issue. instead of adding tooltip on td, insert a div or span element and apply the same.

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span [matTooltip]="row.title" matTooltipPosition="below"> {{ (row.title && row.title?.length > 20) ? ((row.title).slice(0, 20) + '...') : row.title }}</span>
</td>
```

Note- This workaround not working fully, but this will fix the placement of tooltip to some extent.